# MVC3 with razor web.config authorization for default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-authorization

I am new to MVC and my question is this how can I setup my sites root to point to a specific Controller + Action and then in the Web.config file set the location + path of the root of the site, so eg: http://localhost:8080/ to be able to be accessed by all anonymous and logged in.

I have been playing with the location and path but just cant figure it out and in my Global.asax, I am not sure I have the right root to Home + Index as controller + Action.

Here is some code:

**web.config (snippets)**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I am not sure what the `<location path="">` of the root of the site should be.

**Global.asax (snippets)**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
}
```

The default route in Global.asax for the site I would like it to go to the *Home Controller* and the *Action Index*, so when you type http://localhost:8080/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already doing it in the third parameter of `MapRoute`.

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

These specify your default controler and action, exactly as you want it.

Comment: Ok, I guessed as much but what about the authorization location+path in the web.config so I can type http://localhost:8080 and it will pass authorization, because currently it sends me to the login page which is the Account controller + LogOn Action?

Comment: The reason for my above comment is that I would like to keep authorization I have set for forms authentication to apply throughout the site and just put a location+path element extra in the web.config for the root. And I already have <location path="Home/Index"> setup.

Comment: You control that with the [Authorize] attribute either on Action or Controller level. It may be also applied as a global filter. Form what you're saying it looks like you have it set on your Home controller or its Index action.

Comment: Sorry haven't seen the second comment. The best way to go for you is to use the [Authorize] attribute on all the controllers but the Home. In the Home one on all the actions but the Index.